# Symfony 3 + FOSUser + extending Form = namespace error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Using symfony 3 I am trying to extend the default register form following [this tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/overriding-default-registration-form-fosuserbundle/) but I am getting a namespace error like this:

`Attempted to load class "RegistrationType" from namespace "UserBundle\Form".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

The problem seems to occur at the `config.yaml` and if I add a line `- { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/Form/RegistrationType.php" }` it does fix the problem until I refresh the page. I do not understand why..

here is my form extension:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType

{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

{
    $builder->add('firstname');
    $builder->add('lastname');
}

public function getParent()

{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
}

public function getBlockPrefix()

{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}

public function getName()

{
    return $this->getBlockPrefix();
}

}
```

my config.yml

```
# FOSUSerBundle
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: api
  user_class: ApiBundle\Entity\User
  from_email:
    address:        %client_mail%
    sender_name:    %client_name%
  registration:
    form:
        type: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

my bundle

```
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{

  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
  }

}
```

and my service

```
app.form.registration:
  class: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
  tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

Comment: where did that exception occur? share position and line number

Comment: @Trix the profiler highlights an error `in web/app_dev.php (line 28)` which is `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` I can't see much more, please let me know if I can provide something else

Comment: simply run the app in dev mod and check the exception on screen

Comment: that's what I am doing and that is the exception I gave you earlier. The profiler gives no other information except ClassNotFoundException